# Cut a view in wave shape in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, swift4, uibezierpath, xcode9.4

I'm trying to create a view like below programmatically. I believe I would need to use Beizer path, but not sure how should I go about the path points? Any help is appreciated

[image]

```
func createShape() -> UIBezierPath {

    // create a new path
    let path = UIBezierPath()

   //Need to determine path points here
}
```

Comment: Check this tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/2743-core-graphics-tutorial-arcs-and-paths

Comment: Personally, I probably start out with [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com), visually generate the spline your want, export the result out to code (yes, PaintCode does that) and copy and past the resulting code based on your needs. Trying to generate the path by code alone is going to be a lot of work

Answer (score 2):

For the kind of shape you need please refer bellow code ,hope it will help you

```
 let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 300))

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 200))
        path.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y:150),
                      controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 350),
                      controlPoint2: CGPoint(x:150, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width, y: view.frame.size.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: view.frame.size.height))
        path.close()

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        view.layer.mask = shapeLayer
        self.view.addSubview(view)
```

and here is my output
[image]